# Very Long delay before starting actual execution of a unit test Test script in VS2019

Tags: c#, unit-testing, delay, execution

For one of my ongoing project i am using C# to develop quite a few test script.
I am observing a delay of around 2.5 mins to start actual execution of the test script on my machine. Instead if i use the same solution on another machine the script completes execution in few seconds. I have checked with the Hardware configuration of the machines but its the same.
I have tried to execute scripts on different machines but on 2-3 machines i observe same issue as of on my machine but on 2-3 other machines it works completely fine, i mean in few seconds script completes its execution.
Can anyone help me out to analyze and fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is any unit-test take so long or a *specific* one? Start with posting [mcve].

Comment: Nope, there are around 32 scripts and all of them has same behavior.

Comment: Any TestCaseSource attributes (or corresponding attributes for frameworks other than nunit)? These are evaluated before the first test starts.

Comment: I would check the version and location of any loaded unit test assemblies. It might be possible that it tries to do some operation that times out after a while, but has a fallback that succeeds. ProcessMonitor could perhaps be used to inspect what the process is doing.

Comment: Thanks in advance but i wonder how it becomes different on different machines? Is there any possibility of Nuget packages installed can be culprit? Not sure just a wild guess.

Comment: Jonas, did you get anything?